# Extract Data from Website to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to extract data from `https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/how-to-participate/org-details/XXXXXXXX` to a Google Sheet. I tried to use  `importxml` function to extract data in to columns as per below, there is a ID no for each company name when the `XXXXXXXX` is replaced from the ID no and browsed it goes to the page.

```
TYPE OF ORGANISATION // TAGS/KEYWORDS // DESCRIPTION // PROJECTS FUNDED
```

I have 500 links per Google sheet. This is the link for the Google Sheets file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eg63AqD-pcXc7VqyIbJStf9hLtq0WYuXoUU917aW3Lw/edit?usp=sharing

How can I get a code fixed for this matter?

This is were the required information are on the website

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are exactly in the case described here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun where the content is generated dynamically by javascript (see the source where you can find <!-- Sitemap Generator -->). When you apply what is recommended by disabling javascript, you will only find the dynamic logo. And even in this case the content are not embedded in one json object. The page call for content after loading by async procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) with puppeteer for web scraping; find the API [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v8.0.0/docs/api.md). You will probably need to play around and target the specific [selectors](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v8.0.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1). Not sure on how to export this further onto Google Sheets, probably as a csv/json (if supported) file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)? Even if you're not, if you have any sort of programming experience, you'll find Apps Script very easy to learn. It's just JavaScript that you can run from a Google Sheet. Go to **Tools > Script editor** in your Google Sheet to get started.

I recommend [`UrlFetchApp()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for this project. It is a very simple tool for making basic HTTP requests to fetch a webpage and can be used for lightweight web scraping. Once you have the response from `UrlFetchApp`, you can extract your desired content on the page using a library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and targeting the content with [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

The other answer already provided here is certainly also valid, but I think you will find the learning curve for Node.js and Puppeteer much steeper, so I would recommend starting with Apps Script if you are not already experienced with Node. Also, Apps Script is already part of Google Sheets, so you also won't have to deal export/import, which is convenient.